# How to increment row in Excel when writing from dataframe using df.to_excel (openpyxl)

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I am using the following code to increment a read of MS Word files in a directory. Then the table is read and stored in a dataframe (I am not showing that part of the code.

```
from glob import glob
files = glob('*.docx')
for i, wfile in enumerate(files[:-1]):
```

So my question is how do I modify the code below so the row is incremented to allow for the next dataframe to be copied to it. More specifically, the next MS word file that is read, the table data in the file is copied to a dataframe, and the new dataframe is copied to the next row in Excel?

```
df3.to_excel(writer, 'sheet7', header = False, index = False, startrow = 1)
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing this in a cycle, you can add a variable for current row.

```
pos = 1
for i, wfile in enumerate(files[:-1]):
    df3 = ...
    df3.to_excel(writer, 'sheet7', header = False, index = False, startrow = pos)
    pos += df3.shape[0]
```

Comment: Michael, thanks for sharing this. I have already incorporated your code, but it looks like something else in other parts of my code is allowing the loop to continue as it stops on the first word file. The second word file is read, but it is not being passed to the dataframe.  
Question:what is this line of code doing?  --- >  pos += df3.shape[0]
I get that it will increment the row, but don't understand why it is associated with df.shape attribute.
Regards, 
Gus

Comment: It adds a number of rows in your dataframe to the current position in Excel file.

Comment: Michael, I had major issues with my code until I finally fixed it by setting the enumeration to 4 --- > wfile in enumerate(files[:4]): instead of -1. I had four files in my directory and only one file was being read. After setting it to 4, it finally works. Why did you recommend -1?

Comment: Because that was in your question? You have to be more specific if you need more detailed answers.

Comment: Michael ... got it. Thanks